# can't show image via <img> tag

Tags: html, image

I am trying to show an image by doing the following:

```
<img class="header" src="banner.png"></img>
```

banner.png is located in the same folder as my .php file. Why can't it find it when I trace it in firebug?

**Solution:**:

What happened was I copied the image via FTP, and the permission was not set to read, doing a chmod solves the issue.

Comment: After reviewing the two answers, we just don't have enough information. In all fairness, it should work. Your src="" must be wrong. What you can do:

Look in chrome or safari, hit the 'network' tab. find banner.png. If it's returning 404, your link is wrong. if banner.png doesn't exist, you're image tag is in the wrong place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you working from a web server (like Apache or lighttpd or Mongrel) or directly from files (you will see file:// in your browser bar)?

If your website is hosted on a web server, make sure the file permissions on the banner.png file are set to allow the web server to access them - otherwise it won't be able to serve the file. Then for all intents and purposes the file doesn't exit. Changing that depends on your host server's operating system.

Shot in the dark here for what you have - on Linux and Max OSX, you can use "chmod 664 banner.png" when in your directory. That setting should be sufficient.

If you are working from files - I think something else is off! Check the permissions anyway.

**UPDATE:** Turns out this was the issue :)

Answer (score 5):

Aside from anything else, an img tag should close itself:

```
<img class="header" src="banner.png" />
```

Other potential, though unlikely, causes include:

- Is banner definitely a .png file?
- Is the filename all lowercase? Banner.png is different to banner.png

Also, credits to animuson in comments: If this script is being included (if you don't know what that is, ignore this possibility), then the path should be relative to the including script, not the included script.

Comment: You could also mention that it's a relative path and the image must exist int he folder that the file is being accessed from, per this example. So many things.

Comment: I am still getting the issue after changing it to a /, and yes the filename is correct

Comment: @aherlambang Can you post some more information? A screenshot of the folder containing your PHP and Banner would be a good sanity check, and then any information on whether this is included by other scripts, or so on. The code you have does work, so we need to work out what's wrong with your setup now :)

Comment: I think we'd probably have been here all MONTH, let alone all day trying to work that one out :P Good spot.

Answer (score 4):

Only thing I see wrong is the fact that you are using a closing tag.  img tags are self closing always

```
<img class="header" src="banner.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps its a permission thing go in terminal

```
sudo su
cd /Library/WebServer/Document
chmod 755 the image file name
```

this will probably fix it
if your problem is localhost